# this php is for converting the one length to other but it is not giving the output

Tags: php

I created this script to calculation of various different types of units
but after running this script I am not getting the answer

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$convertedTemperature    = 0;

/* The condition is entered when the request is of POST type. */
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
   $length= $_POST['length']; # input
   $fromConvertionUnit     = $_POST['fromConvertionUnit'];#input
   $toConvertionUnit       = $_POST['toConvertionUnit']; #input


# this are the condition for  converting the number from one format to other format
   if($fromConvertionUnit == $toConvertionUnit){
       $convertedlength = $length;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'centimeter')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length*100000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'centimeter') {

       $convertedlength = $length*100000;
   }elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'meter') {


       $convertedlength = $length/1000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'millimeter' )
   {
       $convertedlength = $length*1000000;
   }



   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'micrometer')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length*1000000000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'nanometer')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length*1000000000000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'mile')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length/1.609;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit== 'yard')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length*1093.61;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'foot' )
   {
       $convertedlength = $length*3280.84;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'inch' )
   {
       $convertedlength = $length*39370.1;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'Nauticalmile')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length/1.852;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'kilometer')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length/1000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'centimeter')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length*100;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'millimeter')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length*1000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'micrometer')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length*1000000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'nanometer')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length*1000000000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'mile')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length/0.00062137;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'yard')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length*1.09361;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'foot')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length*3.28084;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'inch')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length*39.3701;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'Nauticalmile')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length/0.000539957;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'kilometer')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length/100000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length/100;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length*10;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length*100000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length*10000000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length*0.0000062137119224;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard')
   {
       $convertedlength = $length/91.44;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length/30.48;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length/2.54;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length/185200;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit =='kilometer')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length/1000000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit== 'millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'meter' )
   {
       $convertedlength=$length/1000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit == 'millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length/10;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length*1000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit =='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length*1000000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit =='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length/1.609000000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit =='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length*0.0010936;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length*0.0032808;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length/25.4;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length/1.852000000;
   }
   elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile')
   {
       $convertedlength=$length/1.852000000000   ;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/25400;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/304800;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/914400;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length* 0.00000000062137;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*1000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/10000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000000000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/10000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1.609000000000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/9.14400000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/3.04800000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/2.540000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1.852000000000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1.151;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*63360;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*5280;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*1760;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/0.00000000062137;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.609000000000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.609000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*160934;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.609;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*1609.34;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1094;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1.094;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*91.44;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*914.4;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*914400;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*9.14400000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/1760;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*3;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*36;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length* 0.00049374;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/6076;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*12;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/3;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/5280;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*3.04800000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*304800;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*304.8;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*30.48;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/3.2808;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/3281;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/39370;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/39.37;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*2.54;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*25.4;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*25400;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*2.540000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/63360;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/36;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/12;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length/72913;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*72913.4;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*6076.12;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*2025.37;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.15078;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.852000000000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' &&  $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.852000000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.852000000;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*185200;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*1852;
    }
    elseif($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer')
    {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.852;
    }
    
    
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Temperature Convertor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.6.1/css/pikaday.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/untitled.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg-white portfolio-navbar gradient">
        <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">SimplyCalculate</a><button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarNav"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main class="page contact-page">
        <section class="portfolio-block contact">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="heading">
                    <h2>Length Conversion</h2>
                </div>
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="name">Enter length to be converted:</label>
                    <input class="form-control item" id="temperature" type="number" name="temperature" value="<?php echo (!empty($temperature)) ? $temperature : '' ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="fromConvertionUnit">Convert From</label>
                    <select name="fromConvertionUnit" id="fromConvertionUnit" class="form-control">
    <option selected>Choose</option>
        <option value="kilometer"><b>Kilometer</b></option>
        <option value="meter">Meter</option>
        <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
        <option value="millimeter">Millimeter</option>
        <option value="micrometer">micrometer</option>
        <option value="nanometer">Nanometer</option>
        <option value="mile">Mile</option>
        <option value="yard">Yard</option>
        <option value="foot">Foot</option>
        <option value="inch">Inch</option>
        <option value="Nauticalmile">Nautical mile</option>
    </select></div>
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="toConvertionUnit">Convert To</label>
                    <select name="toConvertionUnit" id="toConvertionUnit" class="form-control">
        <option  selected >Choose</option>
        <option value="kilometer"><b>Kilometer</b></option>
        <option value="meter">Meter</option>
        <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
        <option value="millimeter">Millimeter</option>
        <option value="micrometer">micrometer</option>
        <option value="nanometer">Nanometer</option>
        <option value="mile">Mile</option>
        <option value="yard">Yard</option>
        <option value="foot">Foot</option>
        <option value="inch">Inch</option>
        <option value="Nauticalmile">Nautical mile</option>
</select></div>
                    <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" type="submit" value="Convert">Convert</button></div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="<?php echo (!empty($convertedlength)) ? $convertedlength : '0' ?>"/>
                    
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="page-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="links"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.6.1/pikaday.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/theme.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What _do_ you get?

Comment: nothing its display the answer as 0

Comment: Using what test data?

Comment: Your form variable is called "temperature", but you try to get the value of `$_POST["length"]`. I am surprised you don't get an error message for that. You should check that the form variables have something in them before you try to use them.

Comment: if i am putting any value its just display zero as a output

Comment: by mistakely i had written the wrong variable

Comment: thnk u so much for helping

Comment: No problem. You can easily debug stuff like this with `var_dump()` and `echo()` to see what values your variables have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to refactor that impressive `if(){}` / `elsif(...){...}` tree to something a bit more manageable, you could implement a 'map' (an array) with the metric conversion rates.

Have a look at this snippet:

Array `$map` holds all the metric conversions, with base 'meter'. These conversion rates are used to calculate the user requested metric conversion.

```
<?php
// map base 'meter'
$map = [
    'kilometer'  => 0.001, 'hectometer' => 0.01, 'decameter' => 0.1, 'meter' => 1, 'decimeter' => 10,
    'centimeter' => 100, 'millimeter' => 1000, 'micrometer' => 1000000, 'nanometer' => 1000000000, 'mile' => 0.00062,
    'yard'       => 1.09361, 'foot' => 3.28084, 'inch' => 39.3700787, 'nauticalmile' => 0.0005399568,
];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fromUnit = $_POST['fromUnit'];
    $toUnit = $_POST['toUnit'];
    $result = $map[$toUnit] / $map[$fromUnit];
    echo "1 $fromUnit = " . $result . " $toUnit";
}
?>

<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group"><label for="fromConvertionUnit">Convert From</label>
        <select name="fromUnit" id="fromUnit" class="form-control">
            <option value="kilometer"><b>Kilometer</b></option>
            <option value="meter">Meter</option>
            <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
            <option value="millimeter">Millimeter</option>
            <option value="micrometer">Micrometer</option>
            <option value="nanometer">Nanometer</option>
            <option value="mile">Mile</option>
            <option value="yard">Yard</option>
            <option value="foot">Foot</option>
            <option value="inch">Inch</option>
            <option value="nauticalmile">Nautical mile</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="toConvertionUnit">Convert To</label>
        <select name="toUnit" id="toUnit" class="form-control">
            <option value="kilometer"><b>Kilometer</b></option>
            <option value="meter">Meter</option>
            <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
            <option value="millimeter">Millimeter</option>
            <option value="micrometer">Micrometer</option>
            <option value="nanometer">Nanometer</option>
            <option value="mile">Mile</option>
            <option value="yard">Yard</option>
            <option value="foot">Foot</option>
            <option value="inch">Inch</option>
            <option value="nauticalmile">Nautical mile</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type='submit' name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: But how can i use for any numbers

Comment: this code is just showing the answer for just number 1

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to access the `POST` request you can just check that the element is not empty in the if statement.

You also had the name of the input for length as `temperature` while you was looking for the `length` value in the $_POST.

This should look like this.

```php
<input class="form-control item" id="temperature" type="number" name="length" value="<?php echo (!empty($length)) ? $length : '' ?>">
```

I've completed the changes for the script.

```php
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$convertedTemperature = 0;

/* The condition is entered when the request is of POST type. */
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $length = $_POST['length']; #input
    $fromConvertionUnit = $_POST['fromConvertionUnit']; #input
    $toConvertionUnit = $_POST['toConvertionUnit']; #input

    # this are the condition for  converting the number from one format to other format
    if ($fromConvertionUnit == $toConvertionUnit) {
        $convertedlength = $length;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'centimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*100000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'centimeter') {
        $convertedlength = $length*100000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'meter') {
        $convertedlength = $length/1000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'millimeter') {
        $convertedlength = $length*1000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'micrometer') {
        $convertedlength = $length*1000000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'nanometer') {
        $convertedlength = $length*1000000000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'mile') {
        $convertedlength = $length/1.609;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit== 'yard') {
        $convertedlength = $length*1093.61;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'foot') {
        $convertedlength = $length*3280.84;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'inch') {
        $convertedlength = $length*39370.1;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'kilometer' && $toConvertionUnit == 'Nauticalmile') {
        $convertedlength = $length/1.852;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'kilometer') {
        $convertedlength = $length/1000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'centimeter') {
        $convertedlength = $length*100;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'millimeter') {
        $convertedlength = $length*1000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'micrometer') {
        $convertedlength = $length*1000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'nanometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1000000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'mile') {
        $convertedlength = $length/0.00062137;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'yard') {
        $convertedlength = $length*1.09361;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'foot') {
        $convertedlength = $length*3.28084;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'inch') {
        $convertedlength = $length*39.3701;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'meter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'Nauticalmile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/0.000539957;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'kilometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length/100000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter') {
        $convertedlength = $length/100;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*10;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*100000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*10000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile') {
        $convertedlength=$length*0.0000062137119224;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard') {
        $convertedlength = $length/91.44;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot') {
        $convertedlength=$length/30.48;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch') {
        $convertedlength=$length/2.54;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'centimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/185200;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit =='kilometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit== 'millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit == 'meter') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit == 'millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length/10;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit =='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit =='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1.609000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit =='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard') {
        $convertedlength=$length*0.0010936;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot') {
        $convertedlength=$length*0.0032808;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch') {
        $convertedlength=$length/25.4;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='millimeter' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1.852000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1.852000000000   ;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch') {
        $convertedlength=$length/25400;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot') {
        $convertedlength=$length/304800;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard') {
        $convertedlength=$length/914400;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile') {
        $convertedlength=$length* 0.00000000062137;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length/10000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='micrometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000000000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length/10000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1.609000000000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard') {
        $convertedlength=$length/9.14400000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot') {
        $convertedlength=$length/3.04800000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch') {
        $convertedlength=$length/2.540000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='nanometer' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1.852000000000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1.151;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch') {
        $convertedlength=$length*63360;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot') {
        $convertedlength=$length*5280;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1760;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length/0.00000000062137;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.609000000000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.609000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*160934;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.609;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='mile' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1609.34;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1094;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1.094;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*91.44;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*914.4;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*914400;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*9.14400000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/1760;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot') {
        $convertedlength=$length*3;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch') {
        $convertedlength=$length*36;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='yard' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile') {
        $convertedlength=$length* 0.00049374;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/6076;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch') {
        $convertedlength=$length*12;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard') {
        $convertedlength=$length/3;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/5280;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*3.04800000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*304800;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*304.8;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*30.48;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter') {
        $convertedlength=$length/3.2808;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='foot' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length/3281;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length/39370;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter') {
        $convertedlength=$length/39.37;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*2.54;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*25.4;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*25400;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*2.540000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/63360;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard') {
        $convertedlength=$length/36;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot') {
        $convertedlength=$length/12;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='inch' && $toConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile') {
        $convertedlength=$length/72913;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='inch') {
        $convertedlength=$length*72913.4;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='foot') {
        $convertedlength=$length*6076.12;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='yard') {
        $convertedlength=$length*2025.37;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='mile') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.15078;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='nanometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.852000000000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' &&  $toConvertionUnit=='micrometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.852000000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='millimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.852000000;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='centimeter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*185200;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='meter') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1852;
    } elseif ($fromConvertionUnit=='Nauticalmile' && $toConvertionUnit=='kilometer') {
        $convertedlength=$length*1.852;
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Temperature Convertor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.6.1/css/pikaday.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/untitled.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg-white portfolio-navbar gradient">
        <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">SimplyCalculate</a><button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarNav"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main class="page contact-page">
        <section class="portfolio-block contact">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="heading">
                    <h2>Length Conversion</h2>
                </div>
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Enter length to be converted:</label>
                        <input class="form-control item" id="temperature" type="number" name="length" value="<?php echo (!empty($length)) ? $length : '' ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="fromConvertionUnit">Convert From</label>
                        <select name="fromConvertionUnit" id="fromConvertionUnit" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Choose</option>
                            <option value="kilometer"><b>Kilometer</b></option>
                            <option value="meter">Meter</option>
                            <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
                            <option value="millimeter">Millimeter</option>
                            <option value="micrometer">micrometer</option>
                            <option value="nanometer">Nanometer</option>
                            <option value="mile">Mile</option>
                            <option value="yard">Yard</option>
                            <option value="foot">Foot</option>
                            <option value="inch">Inch</option>
                            <option value="Nauticalmile">Nautical mile</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="toConvertionUnit">Convert To</label>
                        <select name="toConvertionUnit" id="toConvertionUnit" class="form-control">
                            <option  selected >Choose</option>
                            <option value="kilometer"><b>Kilometer</b></option>
                            <option value="meter">Meter</option>
                            <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
                            <option value="millimeter">Millimeter</option>
                            <option value="micrometer">micrometer</option>
                            <option value="nanometer">Nanometer</option>
                            <option value="mile">Mile</option>
                            <option value="yard">Yard</option>
                            <option value="foot">Foot</option>
                            <option value="inch">Inch</option>
                            <option value="Nauticalmile">Nautical mile</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" type="submit" value="Convert">Convert</button>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="<?php echo (!empty($convertedlength)) ? $convertedlength : '0' ?>"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="page-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="links"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.6.1/pikaday.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/theme.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```